# Can someone explain me this behaviour about style and datatrigger?

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

Basically, i have a checkbox which has the IsChecked property binded in the viewmodel. This property is then evaluated inside a datatrigger to decide the color of a progress bar. The Progress bar itself, is styled with the code that i'm going to present.

Now, this code work:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBorderBrushColor}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBackgroundColor}" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

while the following not:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBorderBrushColor}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBackgroundColor}" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>

                                        <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Can you tell me what is missing or what is wrong in the second xaml? (don't mind to the border part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have those backwards: the *second* example works, while the first does not.

The first example doesn't work because the `Rectangle.Fill` binding doesn't make sense.  You're binding the `Fill` to whatever `ProgressBar.DataContext` is.  Change the `Rectangle` definition to:

```xml
<Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
```

`{TemplateBinding XYZ}` is a short form of `{Binding Path=XYZ, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`.  It means "bind to property `XYZ` on the control to which this template is applied".  In this case, the template is applied to a `ProgressBar`, so we are binding `Rectangle.Fill` to the progress bar's `Background`.  When your `Setters` update the background, the rectangle gets updated too.

Comment: perfect. This was the answer i was looking for. I'm don't override often the template of my controls, and sometimes i miss something.